# "for /f" doesn't set variable using cmd.exe batch file

Tags: windows-xp, cmd

```
rmtshare \\server\sharename$ | for /f "tokens=3,4,5 delims=\" %%A in ('find "Path"') DO 
SET path1=%%A\%%B\%%C
echo %path1%
```

It will do everything up to the set area. I want to take out the physical path of the share and turn it into a variable to be used later. My approach is not working, I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: How is it not working? What are the errors or results?

Comment: when i do echo %path1% nothing is there. it goes through the first part then  it will show the set path1=path.first.last then i echo and nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the command you want to run in the FOR loop is on the same line (e.g. `for /f ... do set path1=%%A\%%B\%%C` or, if you have multiple commands, that they are grouped in parenthesis, like so:

```
for /f ... do (
  echo "Setting path1"
  set path1=%%A\%%B\%%C
)
...
```

(Also, do you have [`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) set? If so, you may need to use `!path1!` instead of `%path1%`.)

Comment: They are all on the same line minus the last echo to see if it worked. im not using setlocal

Comment: for /f "tokens=3,4,5 delims=\" %%G in ('rmtshare \\server\sharename$') DO set op=%%G\%%H\%%I


echo %op%



I WIN!

Answer (score 0):

I believe SET is not persistent, you should use SETX to set a variable in command prompt and have it stay outside that CMD session,
afaik, SETX is native on windows 7, but is available on resource kits for older windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include *usebackq* in your options like so:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3,4,5 delims=\" %%A in ...
```